# How do I get rid of borders on linked/JavaScript elements in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hyperlink, border

This is the site in question:

http://www.orlycuisine.com

It works exactly how I want it to in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but in any version of Internet Explorer, strange borders appear around all my linked elements. On my boss's computer, it's causing all kinds of crazy problems. I have tried fixing it through additional CSS rules, but I'm worried this might be causing more problems...

Help! Why can't I get IE co-operate like its brothers?

Example:

```
<a href="#" class="cuistot" onmouseover="MM_showHideLayers('hide_cuistot','','show')" onmouseout="MM_showHideLayers('hide_cuistot','','hide')">
   <img src="images/bar_blank.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Extract the relevant code from your site and post it here. This site is not only for you, but for any future reader. It's very likely that the site does not show the current problem any more after a few weeks, causing this question to be useless.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the border of all images to 0 by adding the following code to your CSS.

```
img { border: 0; }
```